# Android Image permissions

Tags: android, bluetooth, sharedpreferences, android-imageview, mms

my application saves user details as a qr code png image in the android mobile's SD card,

is there a possibility to block the image from being transfered to other smartphones, (ie) blocking the user from transferring the qr image through bluetooth or mms services

can i save the image with permission allowing only to read.

Comment: i think saving the image to your applications internal memory will be the "safest" method available. I put safest in quotes because I dont believe their is a true way to make your file fully read/write proof especially when it comes to users with rooted phones that can access virtually everything in the file system.

Comment: @dymmeh saving a qrcode in other memory is not possible i hope so, because of the size of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't reasonably stop the user from transferring a file on their SD card to another device/user. What you *could* do is attempt to render that file useless. You could store an encrypted file instead of just the image file and have the encryption key generated on the device in the internal directory on first use. This would mean that the encrypted image file is not usable across devices. This is circumventable (by either copying the decrypted file when it's in use or by rooting the device and finding the key), but adds a measure of prevention.

Comment: is there any good example tutorial for image encryption and decryption in android friend

Comment: Highly doubtful, and not that I know of, but it's just a file. Just look for a basic encryption tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

[setWritable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setWritable(boolean,%20boolean))

this should do the trick ...

```
file.setWritable(false, true);
```

You should be able to set permissions this way.  Good Luck!!!